# Delete rows with duplicate value in one column but different value in other columns

Tags: sql

I have table with 3 columns :

```
ID, name, role
```

Some names are duplicated but they all have an unique ID, how do I delete all rows with duplicated name(not all,leave one for each) in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `name` and select the lowest unique `id`. Delete all records that are not in that list

```
delete from your_table
where id not in
(
  select min(id) 
  from your_table
  group by name
)
```

And if you use MySQL you need another subquery since MySQL does not allow you to delete from the same table you are selecting from:

```
delete from your_table
where id not in
(
  select * from 
  (
    select min(id) 
    from your_table
    group by name
  ) tmp_tbl
)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the ID is uniqueidentifier, I'm not sure if it can select the lowest.